# rplidar driver installation problem on Ubuntu

Tags: ros, usb, driver, rplidar, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies for posting here, but since robopeak's rplidar does not seem to have very much on the support side since it does appear to be R&D hardware. My ultimate goal here is to get RPLIDAR to work with rvis so I thought I would attempt as asking here.

I have attempted to get RPLIDAR to talk to Linuxmint 17 system and an Ubuntu 14.04 system. And when I run:

```
$ roslaunch rplidar_ros view_rplidar.launch

Error, cannot bind to the specified serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
```

And the GUI warns:

```
No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [laser] does not exist
```

I believe the problem is that the USB to UART driver is installed with root permissions because I get the same error when I run the rplidar example program:

```
$ ./ultra_simple /dev/ttyUSB0
Error, cannot bind to the specified serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
```

But it runs correctly when I run the above command under root:

```
$ sudo  ./ultra_simple /dev/ttyUSB0
   theta: 151.48 Dist: 00124.75 Q: 10 
   theta: 152.72 Dist: 00126.00 Q: 10 
   theta: 153.95 Dist: 00127.00 Q: 10 
   theta: 155.19 Dist: 00128.00 Q: 11 
   theta: 156.41 Dist: 00130.00 Q: 11 
   theta: 157.64 Dist: 00132.25 Q: 10 
   theta: 158.88 Dist: 00134.00 Q: 11 
   theta: 160.11 Dist: 00137.50 Q: 10 
   theta: 161.33 Dist: 00141.00 Q: 10
```

Is there way to install the driver without root permissions? Below is how I installed the driver:

```
$ cd Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source
~/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source$ make
~/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source$ sudo cp cp210x.ko /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
~/Linux_3.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source$ sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
$insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko: File exists
$sudo insmod cp210x.ko
```

Can I do a simple `chmod`? Or is there a way to run ROS as root? When I run it with `sudo` it get 'command not found':

```
/catkin_ws$ sudo roslaunch rplidar_ros view_rplidar.launch
sudo: roslaunch: command not found
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199561/rplidar-driver-installation-problem-on-ubuntu/) by [casper911ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/21126/casper911ca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My understanding of the best way to handle this, is to add your userid to the 'dialout' group.  The dialout group allows access to the serial ports.

You can do this with the following command.  ${USER} will be interpreted as your current user name, but you could manually type in the username instead.

sudo gpasswd --add ${USER} dialout

You will have to logout and then log back in before the group change is recognized.

(I'm using rplidar with ubuntu 12.04 and ros hydro.)

---

Originally posted by [mrsoft99](https://answers.ros.org/users/20090/mrsoft99/) with karma: 78 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-03**:
`sudo adduser $USER dialout` is the more canonical way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can I do a simple chmod? Or is there a way to run ROS as root? When I run it with sudo it get 'command not found':

No, you don't need to and you should never (well, never ..) do that. See [Rosrun as super user](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user/) (the accepted answer also explains how to solve your problem).

---

Edit:

> [..] I believe the problem is that the USB to UART driver is installed with root permissions [..]

Under Linux, drivers are always installed *as root* (directly or via `sudo`), as that is the only user allowed to do that. The permissions of the [*device file*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Unix_and_Unix-like_systems) (in your case `/dev/ttyUSB0`) can be configured separately.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few days ago, I faced the same problem, too. And I solved the problem by the method below:

Go to the  file directory：/etc/udev/rules.d/, and see whether it has the file named " 50-usb-serial.rules ", well, in my computer, there is no this file, thus I created the file, below is the steps:

1. $ cd  /etc/udev/rules.d/  
   2.  $ sudo touch 50-usb-serial.rules
2. $ sudo gedit 50-usb-serial.rules

And in the file that is opened by the GEdit, write these words:  **KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", GROUP="turtlebot", MODE="0666"** ( in these words, the word " turtlebot " is my user name)

some one told me that after this, I should run this command: " sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart " , but I did not run this command and it  worked, too.

(sorry for my poor English, but I really hope that could help you )

---

Originally posted by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) with karma: 130 on 2014-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathew12](https://answers.ros.org/users/103917/mathew12/) on 2022-10-24**:
Same problem but solved using this method. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi , maybe try this command
but you need to check the port everytime you replug.

> sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0

> roslaunch rplidar_ros view_rplidar.launch

I made my note on blog . https://goo.gl/aKqSvo

And I have the same problem when I try the sample code of rplidar too. stiil not resolve.

---

Originally posted by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) with karma: 196 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on 2018-04-12**:
I guess "sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0"  should be done every single time you restart you computer / terminal. correct me if i am wrong.